# Is there a binary of Scid vs Mac which works on macOS Mojave?

Tags: scid

I had ScidvsMac 4.19 running on my Mac - ScidvsMac-4.19.dmg from https://sourceforge.net/projects/scidvspc/files/mac/ - but after upgrading to macOS Mojave (10.14.1) it doesn't run - the icon just bounces forever.

I have been trying to use macports compilers to compile the latest source but I am just lost in dependency hell right now because I can't seem to install libgcc7 or libgcc8 properly. I might try to blow everything away and start a fresh install ... but wondering if anyone has overcome these problems?

Comment: I've seen this comment https://sourceforge.net/p/scidvspc/mailman/message/36456929/ stating "The 64 bit macOS version is *very* buggy, and will most likely never get
fixed due to it being a TCL issue.

If we get our act together, we will eventually release a 64 bit linux
version of ScidvsPC that will run on macOS". I do wonder if there's an alternative to Scid for the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty old. Did you succeeded to resolve your problem? I am running scidvsmac 4.19 on Mojave without any problem. You may download it here:

http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/#toc3

Best greetings

marek

Answer (score 1):

Since 12 April 2019, Scid Vs PC 4.20 has been available which seems to have fixed the problem for me at least - now works on macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Comment: I upgraded to Catalina and now it doesn't even start ...

Comment: For running on Catalina, see the latest beta 64-bit version, as described by [the developer's post to the mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/scidvspc/mailman/message/36794356/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running ScidvsMac 4.17 with no issues. macOS is Mojave 10.14.2.
You may give it a try at: 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/scidvspc/files/mac/ScidvsMac-4.17.dmg/download

Answer (score -1):

macOS Mojave still supports 32 bit apps. So it should run Scid vs. Mac.